# How can I remove a referenced dll from ALL projects which references this?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

**Question**:How can I remove a referenced dll from ALL projects in the solution?

(In my scenario I want to have EntityFramework.dll to be REMOVED from ALL projects that reference it.)

Is it possible to achieve in one go instead of doing it one by one for each project in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the package via the nuget package manager, then uninstall-package entityframework will significantly help you here

Comment: then you are basically out of luck, as far as I know. You could load the project files into a text editor and do a global search/replace for the xml fragment that describes the dll reference..